# How to Test Xml Writer and get the right output?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a method WriteXml.

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            if (this.value == null)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(this.value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
                return;
            }
            var type = this.value.GetType();

            var memInfo = type.GetMember(this.value.ToString());

            if (memInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                var attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes<XmlEnumAttribute>();

                if (attrs != null && attrs.IsNotEmpty())
                {
                    writer.WriteValue(attrs);

                    return;
                }
            }
            writer.WriteValue(this.value.ToString());
        }
```

When I am testing it with the unit test. i.e.,

```
[Theory]
        [InlineData(null, "")]
        [InlineData(exposureSValue.NA, "N/A")]
        [InlineData(exposureSValue.Last15Days, "Last 15 Days")]
        public void WriteXmlTest([CanBeNull] exposureSValue? policyCustomEnumValue, [CanBeNull] string writtenValue)
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockXmlWriter = this.Mock.Create<XmlWriter>(Moq.MockBehavior.Loose);
            mockXmlWriter.Setup(x => x.WriteValue(writtenValue));

            var policyCustomerEnum = new PolicyCustomEnum<exposureSValue>(policyCustomEnumValue);

            // Act and Assert
            policyCustomerEnum.WriteXml(mockXmlWriter.Object);
        }
```

While I run this unit test I get an error saying

```
The following setups were not matched:
XmlWriter x=>x.WriteValue("N/A");
```

Please help me out with this. I also tried changing the parameter in the test method which is string type to exposureSValue type but it still the same.

I also get an error for "Last 15 Days".

How to get rid of that error message?

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was with the `writer.WriteValue(attrs);`

It was not writing the value in the `attrs`.

I have written in this way and there are no errors in the test case.

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            if (this.value == null)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(this.value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
                return;
            }
            var type = this.value.GetType();
            var memberInfo = type.GetMember(this.value.ToString());

            if (memberInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                var attribute = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes<XmlEnumAttribute>();

                if (attribute != null && attribute.IsNotEmpty())
                {
                    var xmlEnumAttribute = attribute.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (xmlEnumAttribute != null)
                    {
                        writer.WriteValue(xmlEnumAttribute.Name);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.WriteValue(this.value.ToString());
        }
```

Thanks...!!